# No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE msm8974

Tags: android, build, bsp

Now, i am trying to build android source code for Snapdragon8074 Board, but when i run:

```
make –j4 BUILD_ID=APQ8074_KK_V22
```

i got an error as bellow:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.stepcounter.xml ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.sensor.stepdetector.xml ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/qcom/msm8974/WCNSS_cfg.dat:system/etc/firmware/wlan/prima/WCNSS_cfg.dat ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/qcom/msm8974/WCNSS_qcom_wlan_nv.bin:persist/WCNSS_qcom_wlan_nv.bin ignored.

No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE msm8974
make: *** No rule to make target `–j4'.  Stop.
```

What can i do to fix this problem? Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I don't think the "private recovery resources" message is a problem.

Try typing `make -j4` by hand, I think you copy+pasted it from someplace that changed the hyphen to an em dash (Microsoft Word does that kind of thing).

Answer (score 0):

go to the "out" directory and delete the corresponding output files:

> > out/target/product/xxx/data/app$ rm HelloActivity* -rf